# Calling Public Subroutine in userform Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I recently started to learn excel vba and at the moment I am stuck calling Public Subroutine from a userform Excel VBA. I have been trying to put the subroutine into a module and few other places but still it gives me an error.(Sub or Function not defined!)

Can you please guide in the right direction.

The function itself in module1

```
Public Sub Check(j As Integer)   
If Worksheets("VBA").Cells(j, 19).Value = "Y" Then
    imgA.Visible = True
    imgB.Visible = False
    imgC.Visible = False
    imgD.Visible = False
ElseIf Worksheets("VBA").Cells(j, 19).Value = "N" Then
    imgA.Visible = False
    imgB.Visible = True
    imgC.Visible = False
    imgD.Visible = False
ElseIf Worksheets("VBA").Cells(j, 19).Value = "X" Then
    imgA.Visible = False
    imgB.Visible = False
    imgC.Visible = True
    imgD.Visible = False
ElseIf Worksheets("VBA").Cells(j, 19).Value = "F" Then
    imgA.Visible = False
    imgB.Visible = False
    imgC.Visible = False
    imgD.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Here I am calling it in a userform

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Call Check(i)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Call Module1.Check(i)`

Comment: When you call Call Check(i) in Sub UserForm_Initialize() where does i come from? Is there more code than you've posted?

Comment: I have tried that previously then there is another error "Method or data member not found"

Comment: yeah i is just a public variable which set to equal to 24

Comment: Drop the `Call` and just have `Module1.Check i` - you won't need the parenthesis anyway

Comment: now I got this "Run time error 424 Object Required" error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not intended as an answer to your current problem. Just a suggestion:

```
Public Sub Check(j As Integer)   
    Dim v
    v = Worksheets("VBA").Cells(j, 19).Value

    imgA.Visible = (v = "Y")
    imgB.Visible = (v = "N")
    imgC.Visible = (v = "X")
    imgD.Visible = (v = "F")

End Sub
```

Comment: Short, nice and clean